# NPAPI XCode linker

Tags: xcode, firefox, linker, npapi

I'm trying to compile basic plugin for firefox and linker reports following problem:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NPN_GetValue", referenced from:
      _PluginLog in main.o
  "_NPN_GetStringIdentifier", referenced from:
      _PluginLog in main.o
  "_NPN_GetProperty", referenced from:
      _PluginLog in main.o
  "_NPN_Invoke", referenced from:
      _PluginLog in main.o
  "_NPN_ReleaseObject", referenced from:
      _PluginLog in main.o
  "_NPN_ReleaseVariantValue", referenced from:
      _PluginLog in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

have I missed to add some linked libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just call those functions like you would a normal function (they aren't exported by a browser, nor are you linking against a browser); you need to use the function pointers from the `NPNetscapeFuncs` struct passed to you by the browser.